# How to load a custom script with require.js and make it export an object which I can access in my Backbone views?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I am using require js for handling my Backbone application.

I want to load a script called global (where I'll have several miscellaneous functions which i want to use in certain Backbone views).

Here is the way I confid require js:

```
require.config({

        paths: {
            "jquery" : "libs/jquery",
            "underscore" : "libs/underscore",
            "backbone" : "libs/backbone",
            "text" : "libs/require/text",
            "global" : "libs/global",
            templates: '../templates'
        },

        shim: {

            backbone: {
                deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
                exports: "Backbone"
            },

            underscore: {
                exports: '_'
            },

            text : {
                exports : 'text'
            }
        },

        global : {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports : 'Global'
        }
    });

    require([

        'jquery',

        'underscore',

        'backbone',

        'router',

        'global'

    ], function ($, _, Backbone, Router, Global) {

            console.log(Global);

            Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {

                this.$el.empty();

                this.stopListening();

                this.undelegateEvents();
            };

            var router = new Router();

            Backbone.history.start();
    });
```

As you can see, I am using the **shim config** method for loading the **global.js** file.

I set it's **dependencies**, aka **jQuery**, and name it's export variable "**Global**" `function ($, _, Backbone, Router, Global) {`

How do I need to write the global file, in order to work, and basically, see something except undefiend when I do: `console.log(Global);`

I am thinking of something like this, but obviously isn't working:

On **global.js**:

```
var Global = {

    resize : function () {

        console.log('this will be a resize function')
    }
};

return Global;
```

And on the config file, I should be able to do something like this:

```
require([

        'jquery',

        'underscore',

        'backbone',

        'router',

        'global'

    ], function ($, _, Backbone, Router, Global) {

        Global.resize;

        // Which would execut the resize function


    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Everything should work as you have it - you are just not including it in the shim, so it's not getting exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your shim - I think the `global` object needs to be moved up.

```
    shim: {

        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },

        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },

        text : {
            exports : 'text'
        },

        global : {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports : 'Global'
        }
    },
```

Comment: The order doesn't metter here.

Comment: Not an issue of order, an issue of not in the shim object at all.

Comment: I've worked with require a lot -- having the same issue, now; this is how I've already configured it in my shim -- receiving a load timeout issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should exports Global in global scope in your **global.js**.
Instead

```
return Global;
```

Do

```
window.Global = Global;
```

Then your shim config will work as expected.

Comment: Yes, great idea, but is this method the way to go? I would like to make it work, just like the other libs:  ], function ($, _, Backbone, Router, Global) { - and use global from there, just like you use "_" underscore's object

Comment: @DanyD This what this code is doing. Do not missunderstand me, Global won't be exposed to global scope by RequireJs. It will be available in the same way as Backbone, or underscore.